# How to get the key name and value in dict using index in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have below json:

```
{
    "Static Data": {
        "Maximum Target": "UI-A@supervision-report-production-data-data-1-4:statistics-1:maximum_target",
        "Sigma": "UI-A@supervision-report-production-data-data-1-4:statistics-1:sigma2",
        "Variation Coefficient": "UI-A@supervision-report-production-data-data-1-4:statistics-1:cv",
        "Web Width": "UI-A@supervision-report-production-data-data-1-4:statistics-1:fullwidth"
    },

    "Section": "Winder-A1-roll-1-4:section",
    "StartDateTime": "Winder-A1-3:startTimestamp",
    "StopDateTime": "Winder-A1-3:stopTimestamp"

}
```

below is the code:

```
json_data = open(configs_path)
data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

index = 2

print(data['Static Data'][index])
```

Based on `index`, I want to get the key name and value of the dict. How can I do this.?

Comment: Dictionary is hash map base and it is not support ordering and indexing.

Comment: While Python dict objects maintain insertion order, conceptually they are not ordered objects, and they do not support indexing. Furthermore, JSON objects *are definietly not ordered*, and don't have a concept of index. So you really should re-consider your serialization format if ordering/indexing is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a dictionary into a list of `key`/`value` pairs

```
kvpairs = list(data.items())
```

then `kvpairs[0][0]` will be the first key and `kvpairs[0][1]` the first value.

This is not normally needed very often because the accessing a dictionary by index is somewhat a strange requirement.

Note that the conversion to `list` is necessary if you want to access entries by index, as otherwise the object returned from `items` is only usable for iteration.

If you need instead what is much more common and is iterating over an array then a simple loop using `for ... in` will do:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    ...
```

Comment: Now, now, let's not be too hasty. The object returned by `.items` has other handy uses, like set operations!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: actually I don't like the strange a confusing "lazy" direction that Python took. The semantic is becoming more and more complex and I don't really see what is the gain from that. What is `range(10)` and why is `range(10)[0]` ok and `{1:1}.items()[0]` not? Don't explain that to me: explain it to a novice learning Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an updated version of Python (3.6≤), skip to the second step, otherwise, you will have to follow the first step of loading your JSON in order:

#### Step 1 - Load in Order (On older Python versions (<3.6)):

To do that, you will have to load your json with an `OrderedDict` as the key hook:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open(configs_path) as fd:
    json_data = json.load(fd, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

#### Step 2 - Convert the dictionary (Or inner ones) to list:

You will then have to convert your dictionary into list, so you can access it by index, assuming you want to access only the inner dicts with an index, then you should do something like:

```
for key, value in json_data.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        json_data[key] = list(value.items())
```

Then you can access it like:

```
index = 2
print(json_data['Static Data'][index])
```

Comment: If you are using current versions of Python, OrderedDict is not necessary

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga While I agree with you, he didn't state his current Python version, and thus I've written a solution that would work in either case